# How do I specify local file path to my ssl keystore file in spring application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot

Given I have file in 
    `c:\path\to\file\keystore.jks`

and my application.properties file contains 
    `server.ssl.key-store=c:\path\to\file\keystore.jks`

I get the following exception
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat.2910824355292831382\file:\c:\path\to\file\keystore.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

What is the correct way to specify the path?

Comment: It's a URI! You need to use `file://`.

Comment: FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat.8707914234839952642.1111\file:\c:\path\to\file\keystore.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
This does not work.

Comment: I have also setup a RestTemplate with SSL. Would that be conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which version of tomcat is being used by spring boot. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5377) tomcat versions less than 7.0.66 relativize the server.ssl.key-store setting.

Answer (score 13):

Do not rely on absolute paths. Put the file into same directory as Spring Boot JAR and add this line into your application.properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store=file:keystore.jks
```

Second option is to pass system variable to `-Dserver.ssl.key-store=file:keystore.jks`

Comment: It always prepends the c\windows\temp\tomcat...... before. I think this is the server.tomcat.basedir path.

Answer (score 7):

Below worked for me with Tomcat 8.5.2:

Windows:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: file:C:\<complete file path with extension>
```

Linux:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: file:/J2EE/<complete file path with extension>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.. thanks Yuva..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I made these changes:

1. Set tomcat's version to 8.5.20
2. Changed the property to : file:path

Comment: Tomcat version 8.5 cannot be used with Java6.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `file:` didn't work for relative paths for me.  In summary:

If you put the keystore in your resources, you do this:

```
key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
```

However, if you try this:

```
key-store: file:keystore.jks
```

you will get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no valid keystore
```

So, instead, just do this:

```
key-store: keystore.jks
```

Strangely, if you supply the full path (not relative path), then `file:` will still work.

Answer (score -2):

Just use quotes for keystore file path

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: "/path/to/keystore/keystore.jks"
```

Comment: I have tried quotes this did not make a difference.